# Are Custom Search Site Restricted JSON API and programmable search engine different?

Tags: vertex-ai-search

I received an e-mail saying that Custom Search Site Restricted JSON API endpoints will cease serving traffic on December 18, 2024, and that a transition to Google Cloud's Vertex AI Search must be done.

But all I am using at the moment is a programmable search engine here: https://programmablesearchengine.google.com/controlpanel/all. No programming involved. That's not the same thing, right? This will keep working after December 18 I assume?

I may have gotten the e-mail because we used the JSON API in the past. But I need to be sure if any action is needed on my part.

I have taken no action yet, other than verifying which product we use.